# how do I get this counter function in C++ working?

Tags: c++, linked-list, counter

I'm trying to set up a counter function that will count the number of items in an input file and display the answer in a message box. I think I'm close but I cant seem to get it to work right.
here is my Struct.

```
#pragma region Global Declarations

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

struct PetData
{
    int IdNumber;
    char PetType[25];
    double PetPrice;

    //Count and display the number of items in the linked list
    int CountItems;
    PetData * Link;
};
PetData *Headpointer = NULL;

ifstream DataFile;
ofstream FileOut;

//Create a report listing the records
//that currently comprise the linked list
void ListRecords ( char * );

void InsertItem ( int, char[],double, PetData* );
void OutputItem ( PetData*);



#pragma endregion
```

And here is what i have for the counter

```
 OutputItem ( Headpointer );
 //FinalMessage->Visible=true;

 Headpointer->ListRecords ( OutPutFileName );

 MessageBox::Show ("Listed Printed To Output File \n"
             + Headpointer->CountItems + " Items Were Printed",
             "Report Created", MessageBoxButtons::OK,
             MessageBoxIcon::Information);
         //cleanup
 DataFile.close( );
 FileOut.close( );
 delete CurrentRecordPointer;
 Headpointer = NULL;
```

I appreciate any help you can give. thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific than "I cant seem to get it to work right"?

Answer (score 0):

may be you need something like it ?

```
#pragma region Global Declarations


#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

class LinkedList
{
public:
    struct PetData
    {
        int IdNumber;
        char PetType[25];
        double PetPrice;

        //Count and display the number of items in the linked list        
        PetData * Link;
    };
private:

    PetData *Headpointer;
    ifstream DataFile;
    ofstream FileOut;

    void DeleteItems();
public:

    LinkedList():Headpointer(NULL)
    {        
        OutputItem ( Headpointer );
    };

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        DataFile.close( );
        FileOut.close( );
        DeleteItems();
    }

    //Create a report listing the records
    //that currently comprise the linked list
    void ListRecords (const char * );

    void InsertItem ( int, char[],double, PetData* );    
    void OutputItem ( PetData*);
    int CountItems();    
};



#pragma endregion



        const char * OutPutFileName="out.file";
        LinkedList * list = new LinkedList();        
         //FinalMessage->Visible=true;

         list->ListRecords ( OutPutFileName );

         wstringstream ss;
         ss<<"Listed Printed To Output File \n" << list->CountItems() << " Items Were Printed";
         MessageBox(NULL, ss.str().c_str(), TEXT("Report Created"), MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         //cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
Headpointer->ListRecords ( OutPutFileName );
```

which is equivelent to

```
(*Headpointer).listRecords(OutputFileName);
```

but *Headpointer is a PetData which does not have a listRecords function. That function is declared outside the struct.